# Halmos set theory proof of zorn's lemma. Why we can conclude from hypothesis that $X$ is non-empty?

Tags: set-theory

I am reading Halmos's set theory. Section 16 of the book is **ZORN'S LEMMA**:

> **Zorn's lemma.** If $X$ is a partially ordered set such that every chain in $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ contains a maximal element.

It then goes to explain the basic idea of the proof:

> The basic idea of the proof is similar to the one used in our preceding discussion of infinite sets. **Since, by hypothesis, $X$ is not empty**, it has an element, say $x_1$ ......

Why and from which hypothesis can we conclude that $X$ is not empty? Can't an empty set be a partial order?

### update

definition of **partial order** and **partially ordered set** in the book:

> a *partial order* (or sometimes simply an *order*) in a set $X$ is a reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive relation in $X$.

> A *partially ordered set* is a set together with a partial order in it.

Comment: Have you checked the definition given in the book?

Comment: I'm guessing that there's no obstacle to considering the empty chain (vacuously, all pairs of points in $\emptyset$ are comparable), and such a chain has an upper bound $x \in X$, so... well... there is an $x \in X$.

Comment: The empty set does not satisfy the hypothesis. Suppose it did, that is $X = \varnothing$ satisfies that every chain in $X$ has an upper bound in $X.$ Let $C$ be a chain in $X.$ Then $x \in C \implies x = \varnothing.$ By hypothesis, there exists $x \in X$ such that $x$ upper bounds $C,$ but this is a contradiction.

Comment: @Filippo I updated my question and added the definitions in the book.

Comment: While the empty *partial order* is allowed, so is the empty *chain*. The empty partial order doesn't satisfy the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma since the empty chain in the empty partial order doesn't have an upper bound.

Comment: To reiterate the above comments: See also the two statements of Zorn's lemma given on [its wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma) and the paragraph that follows comparing the two.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So no partial order satisfies the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma since the empty set is a chain of each partial order?

Comment: @Filippo Not at all: if $\mathbb{P}$ is a nonempty partial order, then **every** element of $\mathbb{P}$ is an upper bound of the empty chain in $\mathbb{P}$. Remember, "$x$ is an upper bound of $C$" just means "For every $y\in C$ we have $y\le x$," and that's trivially true for any $x$ if $C=\emptyset$. So the only partial order which the empty chain prevents from satisfying the hypotheses of Zorn's Lemma is the empty partial order.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I thought that the maximal element of a chain is an element of the chain. However, I looked into the book and I was wrong. In fact, there is comment from the author below the lemma concerning precisely this question: "If A is a chain in X, the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma guarantees the existence of an upper bound for A in X; it does not guarantee the existence of an upper bound for A in A"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Noah Schweber pointed out, if $X$ is a partially ordered set that satisfies the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma, then $X$ is not empty:

If $X$ is the empty set, then there is precisely one chain $A$ - the empty set - and this chain does not have an upper bound in $X$, since $X$ is empty.$^1$ But the hypothesis is that each chain has an upper bound, so we get a contradiction.

---

$^1$ However, if $X$ is nonempty, then the empty chain does have an upper bound: "If $A$ is
a chain in $X$, the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma guarantees the existence of
an upper bound for $A$ in $X$; it does not guarantee the existence of an upper
bound for $A$ in $A$" (see the discussion below the statement of Zorn's lemma on page 62).